# setTimeout troubles, trying to slow the code down for 20 milliseconds

Tags: typescript

I have made some progress but the `setTimeout` function is displaying an error of `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`

```
 class PlayerBehavior extends Sup.Behavior {
   speed = 0.08;
   jumpSpeed = 0.35;
   frameSpeed = 1;
   reverseSpeed = -1;

   update() {
     Sup.ArcadePhysics2D.collides(this.actor.arcadeBody2D, 
 Sup.ArcadePhysics2D.getAllBodies());

let velocity = this.actor.arcadeBody2D.getVelocity();

if (Sup.Input.isKeyDown("DOWN"))  {
  velocity.x = 0.000001;
  this.actor.spriteRenderer.setAnimation("Crouch");

  Sup.setTimeout(200){
 //Timeout function here.
    this.actor.spriteRenderer.pauseAnimation();
  }
```

Can someone help please?

P.S I found this within the api it very well may help.

```
  declare namespace Sup {
  function log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;

  // Re-export window.setTimeout & co. with more useful argument orders
  function setTimeout(delayMs: number, callback: Function): number;
  function clearTimeout(id: number): void;
  function setInterval(intervalMs: number, callback: Function): number;
  function clearInterval(id: number): void;

  function exit();

  class Asset {
    name: string;
    path: string;
    type: string;
    constructor(inner: { [key:string]: any; });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (and TypeScript) have an event loop that runs on a single thread.

If you want to perform some work after a delay, you can use a timeout to add an action to the event queue after a specified delay. This will not pause the execution of your program (as this would freeze the whole UI, which also relies on the event queue).
    if (Sup.Input.isKeyDown("DOWN"))  {
        velocity.x = 0.000001;
        this.actor.spriteRenderer.setAnimation("Crouch");
        //This starts the animation what is only 2 sprites running at 10 frames per second
    }

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    //I want the code to wait 0.2 seconds before pausing the animation.
    this.actor.spriteRenderer.pauseAnimation();
}, 200);
```

This will add your function (to pauseAnimation) to the event queue after a 200ms delay. This may execute marginally later than 200ms as the event queue will be processed in order. Unless you have performance issues, this won't be visibly later.

Comment: Is 'window' just a variable?

Comment: `window` represents the global scope in a browser, so is always available. There is a different name for the global scope in web workers and on Node servers - but it is basically the top level in the hierarchy of scopes.

Comment: if (Sup.Input.isKeyDown("DOWN"))  {
      velocity.x = 0.000001;
      this.actor.spriteRenderer.setAnimation("Crouch");
    
      Sup.setTimeout(() => {

        this.actor.spriteRenderer.pauseAnimation();
     }, 200);

Comment: Sorry I am new to this website, formatting is a learning curve but I am not sure if my typescript recognizes `setTimeout` but it does recognize `await` I am just not sure if that could be and or how to use it.